# Build json object with firebase responses

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am building a json object to return data collected from two firebase calls. In development the object comes with data (events). When I build the app and deploy the data (events) returns a null

Here is my code:

```
import admin  from '../../lib/firebase-admin';

const validate = async (token) => {
  let events = null
  let user = null
  if(token){
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token, true);
    user = await admin.auth().getUser(decodedToken.uid);
  }
  admin.database().ref(`events`).on('value', snapshot => {
    events = { ...snapshot.val() }
  })
  const result = {
    data: {
       uid: user ? user.uid : null,
       email: user ? user.email : null,
      emailVerified: user ? user.emailVerified : null,
      events: events
    },
  };
  return result;
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = JSON.parse(req.headers.authorization || '{}');
    const result = await validate(token);
    return res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const result = undefined;
    return res.status(200).send(result);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `once()` instead of `on()` to [query Realtime Database a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once) in this case.  `on()` is asynchronous and is for adding persistent listeners that continue to receive data over time.  `once()` is also asynchronous, but it returns with a single promise that resolves with the snapshot of data.

```
const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`events`).once('value');
events = { ...snapshot.val() }
```